# How to read 3 json files

Tags: go

I am trying to read json data from 3 different json files, there json files name are students1.json, students2.json, and the third one is interns.json.
My first issue: I get error in errr := json.Unmarshal(Database, &database) the error is  (type Database is not an expression)

Second issue: I don't know how to add the third json file with the other (the one have different name interns.json)

This is my code:

```
type Database struct {
    FirstName string `json:"first"`
    LastName  string `json:"last"`
    Email string `json:"email"`
```

}

```
func main() {
fileIndex := 1 // 2 json file
for i := 1; i <= fileIndex; i++ {
    fileName := fmt.Sprintf("%s%d%s", "students", i, ".json")

    // open json file
    jsonFile, err := os.Open(fileName)

    defer jsonFile.Close()
    byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)
    var database []Database
    json.Unmarshal(byteValue, &database)
    errr := json.Unmarshal(Database, &database)
    if errr != nil {
        panic(errr)
    }
}
}
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: Why are you calling `Unmarshal` twice? The first time is the correct one, just check the error (and the other errors you are ignoring)

Comment: As for getting all files, just have a slice of filenames and iterate over it. eg: `fileNames := []string{"students1.json", "students2.json", "interns2.json"}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the filenames into a slice and also take a slice of `Database`. Then just read the files and `unmarshal` them into `Database`.

```golang
func main() {
    fileNames := []string{"students1.json", "students2.json", "interns.json"}
    databases := []Database{}
    for _, file := range fileNames {
        jsonData, err := ioutil.ReadFile(file)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        db := Database{}
        err = json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &db)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        databases = append(databases, db)
    }
    fmt.Println(databases)
}
```